# Cannot open include file "d3dx9.h"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, directx-9

**Edit:** Of course, immediately after working on it for an hour then posting here, I found the stupid mistake...

I'm getting compiler errors when trying to `#include <d3dx9.h>` in a project.  I'm receiving "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h': No such file or directory".

- I do have the DirectX SDK installed (I also just tried reinstalling it to no avail).
- In the Project Properties:

  - VC++ Directories are set to "`$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)`" and "`$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86;$(LibraryPath)`" for Include and Library directories respectively for all configurations—and the environment variable `%DXSDK_DIR%` points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\` as expected.
  - C/C++ > General settings has `$(DXSDK_DIR)include` listed in the Additional Include Directories
  - Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies has `d3dx9d.lib` included for Debug and `d3dx9.lib` included for Release configuration.
- I *am* able to successfully compile and run tutorial projects from the DirectX Sample Browser.
- Visual Studio's Intellisense/autocomplete will find `d3dx9.h` and suggest type and function names that are within the file (and not included through anything else I'm `#include`ing) so it seems that Intellisense can find it.

Any suggestions on what I'm forgetting or what else to try?

Thanks

Comment: Add an answer with what you did, and select it.  Deleting negates the effort Liviu put into helping you.

Comment: Ok.  I wasn't sure if answering my own question was bad form.  Will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't realize that one of the other projects in the solution was `#include`ing a file that was `#include`ing a file that was `#include`ing `d3dx9.h` and I hadn't added those paths to that project.

/facepalm

Answer (score 17):

you forgot one thing:

1. Go to VC++ Directories -> Library Directories
2. add `$(DXSDK_DIR)LIB\x86`
3. apply.

Done. Hope this helps

Comment: I thought he mentioned he included the library directory already.

Answer (score 8):

You should make sure you have **ALL** paths sorounded by quotes (").
Instead of `$(DXSDK_DIR)include` you should have `"$(DXSDK_DIR)include"`

Comment: My understanding is that VS2010 doesn't require quotes around paths; but, either way, adding quotes didn't fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Find the file on your computer, and add it's folder to the properties of your project.

Assuming you have visual studio: `Properties/C/C++/General/Additional Include Libraries`.

Comment: That actually solved the problem for me, but I find it really obscure. Why is it not sufficient to have the directory listed in "VC++ Directories -> Include Directories"? Can you elaborate on the differences between that and the setting you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of these suggestions and none worked.

Turns out the $(DXSDK_DIR) variable doesn't work if you install DirectX while Visual Studio is still running. The solution for me was to restart Visual Studio (+ adding the paths in the solutions listed above, of course).