# Why can't I compile this opensource project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx

I downloaded the source code from http://construct.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/construct/ using tar ball http://construct.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/construct/?view=tar

There is a visual studio solution file in IDE subdir I converted in VS2010. When compiling I got 56 Errors like

> Error 1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h': No such file or directory C:...\construct\construct\ide\stdafx.h 106 1   Construct

Why? How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you either don't have DirectX SDK installed and/or include directories for project (or global settings in VS) are not properly set.

Does this help: [Cannot open include file "d3dx9.h"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931151/cannot-open-include-file-d3dx9-h)