# Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, include

Befor posting I read [[Cannot open include file "d3dx9.h"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931151/cannot-open-include-file-d3dx9-h) ] and [[Cannot open include file "d3dx9.h"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931151/cannot-open-include-file-d3dx9-h) ] But none worked.

My Compile error:

> Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h': No such file or directory

I do have `d3dx9.h` in project directory but it doesn't detect it and neither it shows it in `External Dependencies`

Any help?

Source Code:

`#include <d3dx9.h>`